# Looping over several files in bash

Tags: vcf, bash, linux, wgs

I have a bash script:

I am wondering how I can change this script to loop over a bunch of .vcf files and give output .txt with the name of corresponding .vcf

I tried changes done in similar script in  [Changing this code in a way to work for my files](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11061/changing-this-code-in-a-way-to-work-for-my-files/11067?noredirect=1#comment15031_11067) but I just  messed everything up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we save the script pasted in the main post as a sh file and we have some .vcf files in a folder, by this line we can iterate over vcf files to extract what mentioned in the script returning .txt output by the name of corresponding vcf

`for file in *.vcf ; do bash indel_vcf_parasing.sh $file ; done`

Comment: Can you provide some context to future readers about this answer

Comment: This is generally the method I use for scaling. Write a program to do 'one', then write wrappers, or use one-liners (as this answer shows) to do many.

You will need to be sure that successive runs do not step on each other (if using a single directory for all runs), or make a new directory for each run if necessary.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the extra details so the answer is complete and a user doesn't have to read all the comments to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Error means that quotations are missing. I am not going to review this chunk but at first glance check

```
printf 'TumorAltAlleleCount\tTumorAltAlleleFrequency\t'\n'
```

There are three quotation marks so one is not matched. I suggest you develop code within a good IDE that will help you debug. Please google around for potential solutions. I personally do R and Shell scripting in RStudio. It differently colors quoted and unquoted code so you immediately see if you missed a closing quotation somewhere.